# Android Studio custom notification

Tags: javascript, android, xml

I'm working on an android app project and I'm stuck at creating the notifications. I'd need a notification that notifies every 15th day every month. Any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please [edit] your question and add some [mcve] that you have tried so far. StackOverflow isn't code writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a android service that checks the date. Show the notification when the date you specify.
You can see how create a background service: [enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html)
Example for taking the day(15th):
I wrote it in java but you can also use android studio.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;  
import java.text.DateFormat;  
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;  
import java.util.Calendar;  
import java.util.Date;  
public class Main{

  public static void main(String[] args) {




        Date today = new Date();  

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();  
        calendar.setTime(today);  

        calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);  
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);  
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);  

        Date lastDayOfMonth = calendar.getTime();  

        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");  
        System.out.println("Today: " + sdf.format(today)); 
        String[] str = sdf.format(today).split("-");
        System.out.println("" + str[2]);
        if(str[2].equals("15"))
           System.out.println("today is 15th" );
           else
           System.out.println("not yet...");
      }
    }
```